# A Model That Contains Other Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I may have the terminology a bit off, but I'm going to try to explain this as much as possible.

I'm currently working on an application that has different types of products: suits, shoes, shirts.  These are all separate models that don't have a similar point of inheritance.  A User, who owns a Collection, should be able to add one or many of these to the Collection.

I was thinking of using has_many :through, but that does not seem very elegant.  I would have to create 3 similar joining tables for each model (or so I think).  Is there a better solution?  And if the solution requires I modify the structure as is, is there another solution that I could get by with for now?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If user own a collection, than suits, shoes and shirts must belong  to user. Also, you need to use nested attributes. So, you'll have something like:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :suits
has_many :shoes
has_many :shirts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :suits
accepts_nested_attributes_for :shoes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :shirts
```

**shirts**

```
belongs_to :user
```

And  than, you can use this form code to add products:

```
form_for @user do |f|
 f.fields_for :shoes, @user.shoes.new do |builder|
  builder.text_field :price
  ...
 end
 f.fields_for :suits, @user.suits.new do |builder|
  builder.text_field :price
  ...
 end
end
```

Comment: Ahhh, ok.  So, I should just skip creating a container for them that belongs to the User?  It just seemed slightly dirty, but I feel a bit better about your approach.

Comment: I feel it requires a different controller, like it would clutter the user controller a bit much.